# Where must variables in PowerShell here-strings be initialized?

Tags: powershell, heredoc

I have a rather complex SQL query I want to use in a here-string in a PowerShell script. Inside the query, I want to replace certain values with PowerShell variables. I'm trying to understand exactly where I need to declare and initialize the variables that will be used in the here-string.

Simplified example:

```
$SqlQuery = @"
update MyTable 
set foo = $bar
where baz = $quux
"@

...

foreach ($part in $parts) {
    $bar = $part[0]
    $quux = $part[1]

    Run-SqlNonQuery $SqlQuery    #Run-SqlNonQuery is a funct. that executes the query
}
```

I'm declaring the here-string at the top, and it references a couple of PowerShell variables, $bar and $quux, that change each time thru the loop.

However, I'm getting errors when I run my script. When I run a SQL trace, there's no value where the PowerShell variables appear in the PS script.

Do the PowerShell variables get interpolated when called in a here-string like this? Do I need to put the entire here-string *inside* the loop where the variables are initialized? What's the right structure for something like this?

I'm running PowerShell on Windows 7, .Net 4, VS2010. I'm not clear on the version; `$Host` returns

```
Name             : PowerConsole
Version          : 1.0.30222.0
```

but `$PSVersionTable` returns

```
PSVersion             2.0                                                      
PSCompatibleVersions  {1.0, 2.0}
BuildVersion          6.1.7601.17514
```

Comment: Perhaps you can solve the task even better if `Run-SqlNonQuery` supports SQL parameters. Does it?

Comment: @Roman, no, it doesn't -- I was going down that path and found myself about to write a whole SQL DAL in PS to support stored procs, arbitrary params, etc, and it was a LOT of overhead for not much benefit. The Scripting Way seemed to be to do variable replacement or interpolation, and it was nice and simple, except not giving the results I needed. I now have two solutions to choose from -- one with easy syntax but you have to count placeholders, and one that uses descriptive variable names but a bit more obscure syntax.

Comment: Alas, then. Mind the issue: if you are going to deal with string data in this way (interpolation of variables), do not forget to escape single quotes with one more (replace `'` with `''`).

Comment: Thanks, good tip about the quotes. In most cases my variables are for text inside the quotes, like `set foo = '{0}'`, but not always!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edited to include Mark's suggestion**
assumes you match the order of the array in part to the order used with {x} etc..

```
$SqlQuery = @"
update MyTable 
set foo = {0}
where baz = {1}
"@

...

foreach ($part in $parts) {
    Run-SqlNonQuery $SqlQuery -f $part    #Run-SqlNonQuery is a funct. that executes the query
}
```

---

Original version

this should do the job

```
$SqlQuery = @"
update MyTable 
set foo = {0}
where baz = {1}
"@

...

foreach ($part in $parts) {
    $bar = $part[0]
    $quux = $part[1]

    Run-SqlNonQuery $SqlQuery -f $bar, $quux     #Run-SqlNonQuery is a funct. that executes the query
}
```

If you want more info Google "powershell string formatting"

HTH,
Matt

Comment: PS. PowerShell Version 2 is shipped with Windows 7. 

Comment: Oh, very cool! I was focused on variable interpolation, didn't think of string formatting -- this works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: The string formatter takes arrays: `Run-SqlNonQuery $SqlQuery -f $part` would work, too. Saves you creating variables just to pass them on.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (single quoted here-string):

```
$SqlQuery = @'
    update MyTable 
    set foo = $bar 
    where baz = $quux
'@

foreach ($part in $parts) 
{
    $bar = $part[0]
    $quux = $part[1] 
    $q = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($SqlQuery)
    Write-Host $q
    #Run-SqlNonQuery $q
}
```

<strike>Generally you need you declare the here-string after you assign the variables (inside the loop). You can use a sub-expression to expand the values (e.g $(...)):</strike>

```
foreach ($part in $parts) {

$SqlQuery = @"
    update MyTable 
    set foo = $bar 
    where baz = $quux

"@

$bar = $part[0]
$quux = $part[1]    

Write-Host $($SqlQuery)
#Run-SqlNonQuery $($SqlQuery)
}
```

Comment: Won't the here-string have empty values for $bar and $quux in the first iteration, and then be one pass behind each iteration after that?  Did you mean to use single quotes on the here-string?

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to avoid -- the here-string is quite long, and I really didn't want to re-declare it in each loop iteration, nor clutter my loop with a big, mostly-static declaration. It technically works, but is not the best solution.

Comment: @Shay, now that's better! A little wordy to explicitly call ..ExpandString(), but that makes what's happening clear, and keeping named variables in the here-string is a nice bonus. +1.

Answer (score 1):

As Shay notes, the variables in the here-string need to be declared before they're used in the here-string. I've had occasion to want to move it just to make the script easier to read / maintain, and used a script block:

```
$MakeHereString = {
@"

Variables 1-3 are:
Variable 1 = $variable1
Variable 2 = $variable2
Variable 3 = $variable3
"@
}

$Variable1 = "First"
$Variable2 = "Second"
$Variable3 = "Third"

&$MakeHereString

Variables 1-3 are:
Variable 1 = First
Variable 2 = Second
Variable 3 = Third
```

For your example:

```
$SqlQuery = {
@"
update MyTable 
set foo = $bar
where baz = $quux
"@
}
...

foreach ($part in $parts) {
    $bar = $part[0]
    $quux = $part[1]

    Run-SqlNonQuery (&$SqlQuery)    #Run-SqlNonQuery is a funct. that    executes the query
}
```

Comment: This is a bit better than Shay's solution, since the here-string is outside the loop, but the syntax is much clumsier than Matt's solution: the script block and sub-expression are not obvious to write, and not easy to read. It works, but Matt's string formatting solution is best (and first!) Thanks, tho.

Comment: I guess it's subjective. I'd consider the replacement of the descriptive variable names in the here-string with the format enumerations to make the here-string harder to follow and debug, particluarly if it's long and contains many substitutions.

Comment: yes, definitely subjective; I agree that it's easy to get lost counting placeholders. But when I saw "$(&$SqlQuery)" I thought of a cartoon character cursing at me ;-) -- just a bit too much magic there for my taste (now I gotta look up what that ampersand does!)

Comment: It looks like I may have erred with the $.  It's not really necessary.   Run-SqlNonQuery (&$SqlQuery)  seems to work just as well, if that makes it easier.

Comment: Cool, I'll give that approach a shot, too. Thanks!